# Setting SelectedItem of Listbox or ComboBox through ViewModel MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, selecteditem

Objective:  having bound the SelectedItem of a ListBox (or ComboBox) to an instance of an object through xaml, I would like to set the selected instance of the object through the view model and have it reflect on the ListBox or ComboBox.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboServers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="535,694,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Settings.Servers}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Settings.SelectedServer, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="UserFriendlyName">
```

C# Model View code

```
public ObservableCollection<AutoSyncServer> Servers { get; set; }

private AutoSyncServer _selectedServer;

public AutoSyncServer SelectedServer
{
    get { return _selectedServer;}
    set
    {
        _selectedServer = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedServer");
    }
}
```

The list or combo box populates correctly.  Selecting an item on the ListBox or ComboBox will correctly set the SelectedServer object.

However, if I try to write a set statement in C# such as:

```
Servers.Add(newServer);
SelectedServer = newServer;
```

The ListBox or ComboBox will correctly add the item and the SelectedServer object will be correctly set on the MVVM model, but the front end will not reflect this selection.

In this specific case, an xml file is read saying what the user had selected last, and when the window opens the ComboBox has nothing selected (the servers are all loaded correctly within it though)

What's missing here?

Comment: Check for any binding issues errors while debugging.

Comment: What is "OnServerChanged"? Your view model class should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise the PropertyChanged event. Does it?

Comment: OnServerChanged has nothing to do with the issue as this issue comes up in other areas as well.  OnServerChange lets me know a server changed so that server objects can be retrieved.  I will edit this out of the problem.

Comment: @mm8 There's a common pattern where a particular property, and changes in its value, is of particular interest, so you write a `FooChanged` event with specialized EventArgs, to spare consumers the relative annoyance of handling `PropertyChanged` and checking the property name.

Comment: How are you actually setting the SelectedServer property?

Comment: XML Deserialization.  

The SelectedServer is serialized.  It comes back from the xml file and is changed correctly and fires the OnPropertyChanged method correctly but the drop down does not ever seem to notice and stays blank.

Answer (score 2):

The actual object in `SelectedItem` *must* be an object instance which is found in the `Servers` collection, in the `Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)` sense. Not just the same Name and ID (or whatever) properties; the same exact class instance.

The classic case where people run afoul of this is deserializing equivalent items in multiple places. `Servers` has a collection of deserialized `AutoSyncServer` instances, and `Settings.SelectedServer` is a separately deserialized `AutoSyncServer` instance, which has identical property values to one of the items in `Servers`. But it's still a different object, and the `ComboBox` has no way of knowing that you intend otherwise.

You could override `AutoSyncServer.Equals()` to return true if the two instances of `AutoSyncServer` are *logically* equivalent. I don't like doing that because it changes the semantics of the `=` operator for that class, which has bitten me before. But it's an option.

Another option is to have one canonical static collection of `AutoSyncServer` and make sure every class gets its instances from that.

---

I don't understand why this code didn't work, given the above:

```
Servers.Add(newServer);
SelectedServer = newServer;
```

Once `newServer` is in `Servers`, it should be selectable. I tested that and it's working for me as you would expect.

Comment: I guess I dont' understand how that works.  There is already a master collection of ObservableCollection type.  I don't understand how you would put a collection over this collection or how you would know what is selected from that master collection.  

The observable collection works great.  When selecting from the list it works fine.  

The problem is ONLY when you are trying to set the SelectedItem from back end code on the model view.  Then the SelectedItem is still being set but the list is not reflecting that change for whatever reason. 

The equals override does make sense to me.

Comment: @auticus I apologize, it seems I didn't read your question carefully. If the C# snippet I quoted is the *only* case where it doesn't work, my suspicion would be that `OnPropertyChanged` might be implemented wrong in Settings. Is `Settings.Server` a static property of a static class by any chance?

Comment: Ed, no nothing is static.  Settings is a class that is instantiated and all properties are instantiated within it.

Your equals override suggestion DOES fix the issue and when overriding equals I do get my listbox select the proper item on deserialization.

Which makes total sense to me, the initial load of servers is not the same object as the selected server object so the hash codes would not match when they are loaded and the list items would never be selected on the back end because of it.

Comment: @auticus Now I'm confused, but if it resolved the issue, it resolved the issue. I'm going to update the answer and remove the bit where I misunderstood you.

Comment: Basically:  the xml sets the collection of servers.  Then it sets the selected server upon deserializing.

This means server FOO is set in the collection of servers.  Then it is also created as the SelectedServer.  The two objects are the same property-wise but have different HASH codes.  So they are different.

So setting SelectedServer on the back end sets Foo with hashCode "AA" as selected, but Servers collection doesn't have a Foo with hash "AA" it has a Foo with hash "AB" or whatever.

Overriding equals to use properties instead fixes the issue.

Comment: @auticus I do know what a hash code is, and I have at least a primitive notion of how equality comparison of reference types works in C#. Pretty sure it was me who brought that subject up. What confuses me is that your C# code didn't work; see my update. The case you show as failing is, in my several years of daily professional WPF programming (confirmed by a test just now), infallible. I'm not saying you're seeing things; I'm wondering what's different in your code.

Comment: My commentary on hash codes was more for general audience in case anyone else came in and read the responses to help them.  

I don't know whats different in my code.  It is exactly as I presented it though now I added an override to Equals on the AutoSyncServer class which resolved the issue.

The code that you are wondering why it doesn't work is not the real problem its the initial deserialization of the object on window load.  (where the issue is the object in the collection != object in selectedItem property due to deserialization)

Your answer clarified the issue.

Comment: @auticus Whoops, misclicked the chat thing. No need for that. Well, I'm glad it got resolved, and it sounds like it's probably for the best that I misunderstood that code sniippet the first time around.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must avoid "sub-bindings", they work once when the view ask for, but not well after
Settings.SelectedServer ==> SelectedServer

and if you comment `OnServerChanged?.Invoke(this, _selectedServer);` what is happening ? it works ?

Comment: OnServerChanged?.Invoke has nothing to do with the issue.  I have the same issue in other areas of code with other ListBoxes that do not implement that, thats simply a call to retrieve Server objects from the listed server.